# Is it possible to tests network section on Chrome by selenium automation tests with C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browsermob-proxy

I want to tests responses and queries from network section in ChromeWebDriver. I saw  mobproxy however, it doesn't have a fresh client for .NET. Do you know anything other? It's very important for me.

Cheers,

Comment: RestSharp is the way to go I think

Comment: @DavidBaak how? I need take HAR file and parse it. Unfortunately, i think RestSharp not help with it :(

Comment: what is the reason you need to parse the HAR? Which kind of information do you want to extract?

Comment: I want to receive information from network section from DevTools Chrome. I found a solution how to do. It's possible to use ChromePerformanceLoggingPreferences and collect data from Network. Thank you, David, that you want to help me

Comment: Sure, glad you found a solution